# How to write appropriate warning messages while writing Gradle plugin?

Tags: plugins, coding-style, gradle, warnings, message

I am trying to write a Gradle plugin and I have a situation in which user specified bunch of files and when the file is not with specific extension then the warning has to be thrown, because these files can not be processed.
So I am wondering if there is a convention how to construct appropriate warning message, so the message to be clear and not to disappear in the thousands line of project log.

I think something like:

```
WARNING!!! The file ${file.getName()} is with incompatible extention type ${extention}. The appropriate extension is ${EXTETNIO_TYPE}. The current file will not be taken during the build."
```

But while looking in the Gradle code. Their warning messages are just the message without **WARNING** or anything else.
Please, give me your advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning messages are typically logged with `log.warn()`. However, if the files cannot be processed, it might be more appropriate to throw a `GradleException`. Warnings should be avoided whenever possible because they create noise, require the user to always check the command line output, and are easily overlooked.

Comment: Fast and accurate as usual. OK I will throw exception but when I need to log warning how to compose my message? To use some leading word or I saw in some logs -----------> and then the message.

Comment: The established practice is to just use `log.warn()`. If you think the message needs to be prefixed, you can do so yourself as part of the message.